# Hiding header on scroll not working as need in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I'm working on React Native App and I'm trying to hide the header on scroll up (from down to up), I found an example and it worked but when I click on the header it clicks on Flatlist item !!

[image: I'm clicking on header]

HomeScreen

[image: This is HomeScreen code]

Header

[image: Header code]

Comment: possible workaroung: Why dont you use `ListHeaderComponent` attribute of the `FlatList` component and pass it the custom header as props

Comment: If i did this the header will hide when i scroll up and never show till i scroll to top of list, I wanna show the header whenever the user scroll down like youtube and linkedin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a try with the medium blog might help you with your requirements.

https://medium.com/swlh/making-a-collapsible-sticky-header-animations-with-react-native-6ad7763875c3

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: remove `{position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, height: 70}` from headerContainer and add it to Animated.View styles